# error 415 при POST посылке xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

Сервер ASP core mvc , стандартный шаблон на VS2015 созданный

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Add([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var str = value;
        return str;
    }
```

Клиент просто на кнопочку в винформ:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Url = "http://localhost:54327/message";

        HttpWebResponse HResp;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        request.Method = "POST";          
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Timeout = 120000;
        request.Accept = "text/xml";

        var messageToSend = new XDocument();
        XElement chatMessage = new XElement("ChatMessage");
        XElement message = new XElement("Message", richTextBox3.Text);
        XElement createTime = new XElement("CreateTime", DateTime.Now);
        chatMessage.Add(message);
        chatMessage.Add(createTime);
        messageToSend.Add(chatMessage);

        string values =messageToSend.ToString();

        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(values);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
        HResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = HResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
        string ResponseReport = reader.ReadToEnd();
        label1.Text = ResponseReport;
        reader.Dispose();
        resStream.Dispose();
        HResp.Close();
    }
```

Все запускается из студии экземпляр "сервера", экземпляр винформы.
После нажатия кнопки получаем:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Net.WebException" в System.dll
>   Дополнительные сведения: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

если сделать curl ом

> C:\Program Files\cURL\bin>curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @y.xml -X POST htt
>   p://localhost:54327/message -v
>   *   Trying ::1...
>   * Connected to localhost (::1) port 54327 (#0)
>   POST /message HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:54327
>   User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Type: text/xml
>   Content-Length: 51
>
> - upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes
>     < HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
>     < Server: Kestrel
>     < X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdFxNb3N0YVxTZXJ2ZXJcTW9zdGEuU2VydmVyXHNyY
>     1xNb3N0YS5TZXJ2ZXJcbWVzc2FnZQ==?=
>     < X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     < Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2016 17:43:32 GMT
>     < Content-Length: 0
>     <
> - Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Самое ужасное, что есть другой проект, написанный на студии 2012 и все работает. Мысли есть, что дело в ИИС експресс, что запускает студия на отладку. Но куда копать уже совсем непонятно.
В чем дело может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, по какой-то причине IIS Express, который идет вместе с Vs2015 по умолчанию не ведает, что существует и можно вот так:
 `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

Поменяв на  'application/json' стало лучше. По крайней мере если посылать string - все работает.